# I am having problems storing values in order table from gridview and result from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm creating a e-commerce cart page in asp.net.On checkout button I want to save user details into database by a stored procedure and from the returned result of the stored procedure I'm getting an id. Further from the grid view I'm getting product details and storing them into order table.

Customer details gets successfully saved. But I can't save values from grid view into order table.

```
using (var db = new ModelDatabaseEntities())
{
    var query = db.GetSelectedItemsDetail(productlist);
    GV.DataSource = query;
    GV.DataBind();
}

protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerId = createCustomer();

    for (int count = 0; count < GV.Rows.Count; count++)
    {
        var Id = GV.Rows[count].Cells[0].Text;
        var Name = GV.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
       // var Price = Convert.ToInt32(GV.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text);
       // var Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(GV.Rows[0].Cells[5].Text);

       // string strDate = DateTime.Today.ToString();
       // DateTime c = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
       using (var db = new ModelDatabaseEntities())
        {
            db.EnterOrder(Convert.ToInt32(Id), CustomerId, 200, 2, "2/3/2014");
            db.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
}

public int createCustomer()
{
    var UserName = txtFirstName.Text + txtLastName.Text;
    var Email = txtEmailAddress.Text;
    var Password = txtPassword.Text;
    var Adress = txtAddress.Text;

    using (var db = new ModelDatabaseEntities())
    {
        CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(db.Register("asad", "raza", "asad",true,"asad", "121313"));
        db.SaveChanges();
        return CustomerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issues here. If you're not getting any error, then plz check thru Debug what is the value & Datatype for CustomerId in db.EnterOrder()?

Comment: Is this webforms? Also, is this test or school code? Because you totally should never do this for a real application. Unless you want it to be super easy for someone to change the price of what they ordered.

Comment: i m getting an error on db.SaveChanges() that states  "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: Your id var is looking at the count variable but the name is using 0 all the time? GV.Rows[count]

Comment: Nikki9696 this is for school and i m new into this.

Comment: Ok, for school this is fine, they're teaching you basic stuff. So what does EnterOrder do?

Comment: Oh, and always look at the inner exception  :)